# Парсинг numbuster.com

Tags: php, html, парсер

Добрый день! Пытаюсь спарсить тег `<div class="descr">Всего возможных имен:  4</div>` с сайта https://numbuster.com/ru/number/380977777777, но в ответ получаю

**"Fatal error: Uncaught Error: Call to a member function find() on boolean in D:\XAMPP\htdocs\dashboard\test\num\numbuster.php:10 Stack trace: #0 {main} thrown in D:\XAMPP\htdocs\dashboard\test\num\numbuster.php on line 10"**

Привожу листинг php файла:

```
   <?php
     include('simple_html_dom.php');
     $result = array();
     $site = file_get_html ('https://numbuster.com/ru/number/380977777777');
     if($_GET['number']=='')
     {
        echo ('Номер не указан');
        exit;
     }
    foreach($site->find('.descr', 1) as $element) // та самая 10-я строка
    $res = $element->plaintext;
    if ($res == "Всего возможных имен: 0")
    {
    echo ("Пусто");
    }
    else
    {
    echo ("Доступно следующее".$res."*");
    }
?>
```

Ребят, подскажите, что делаю не так c simple_html_dom_parser.
Спасибо!

Comment: Ошибка `function *() on boolean` значит, что $site это не объект вовсе 
 а значение `false`  (simpledom не инициализировался). А значит simpledom  не смог скачать страницу 'https://numbuster.com/ru/number/380977777777'

Comment: Проблема может быть из-за того, что сайт расположен на https?

Comment: Может быть. Это вы сами смотрите, как считать ошибки из simpledom. Я бы рекомендовал скачать страницу друними способами, а в simpledom передать уже строку.

Comment: Банально звучит, до даже CURLом не могу получить страницу. Хотя wget отлично справляется. Может кто подскажет, как можно ее побороть именно CURLом? Спасибо

Comment: Ну значит проблема вам уже очевидна. А как курлом получать страницы - информации найдёте предостаточно, единственное из деталей: чтобы игнорировать шифрование https, надо опции `CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYHOST` `CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYPEER` ставить в 0.

Comment: Спасибо, поборол проблему

Answer (score 0):

Проблема была решена подключение внешнего сертификата